# Receiving SMS by Arduino GSM Shield and control the LED with the content of this SMS?

Tags: sms, arduino, gsm, led

I am using Arduino GSM Shield receiving SMS from an Android app. And the content of this SMS will control a LED. If the content of this SMS is not "off", the LED will be on and the content will be printed in the serial monitor. But if it is "off", the LED will be off immediately. Besides, the LED will keep being on until the "off" message coming. For now, I used the code from the example of the software. But I cannot use the content of this SMS to control the status of LED. With the code below, the LED could not be turned on and the content could not be displayed on the monitor. I think it was because the sketch failed to get the whole content of this SMS. Could anybody tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks.

```
#include <GSM.h>
GSM gsmAccess;
GSM_SMS sms;
char senderNumber[20];  
int led=13;
void setup() 
{
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(led,LOW);
while (!Serial) {
  ;
} 
Serial.println("SMS Messages Receiver");
boolean notConnected = true;
while(notConnected)
{
if(gsmAccess.begin("6442")==GSM_READY)
  notConnected = false;
else
{
    Serial.println("Not connected");
    delay(1000);
}
}  
      Serial.println("GSM initialized");
      Serial.println("Waiting for messages");
}

  void loop() 
  {
  char c;
  int val=0;
  val=digitalRead(led);
  if (val==HIGH){
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
  }
  if (sms.available())
  {
  Serial.println("Message received from:");
  sms.remoteNumber(senderNumber, 20);
  Serial.println(senderNumber);

if(sms.peek()=='#')
{
  Serial.println("Discarded SMS");
  sms.flush();
}
   while(c=sms.read())   
  if(c='off'){
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);
}else{
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
  Serial.print(c);
}
  Serial.println("\nEND OF MESSAGE");
  sms.flush();
  Serial.println("MESSAGE DELETED");
}
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this line

```
 if(c='off'){
```

you are setting the value of c to "off".  I guess you want to compare the value of c to the string "off" instead.  Use == instead of =.

Also, what happens if someone sends "OFF" instead of "off"......?  you need to handle that case as well.  Try converting the SMS to lower characters before you do the compare.

Comment: Also neither c='OFF' nor c=='OFF' make much sense as c is declared as char and first operation tries to assign c with address of an 'OFF' string, while second one compares it to the same address.